# How do I improve Azure ML learning performance?

Tags: performance, machine-learning, cloud, azure-machine-learning-service

Training a simple convolutional network to recognize MNIST digits on Microsoft Azure (in Machine Learning Studio) takes many many times longer than it does for (already very slow) learning of exactly the same model locally, on a CPU (MacBook Pro, with limited memory) with TensorFlow.

Is there a way — perhaps purchasing resources or connecting virtual GPUs — to improve performance of Azure Machine Learning?

Answer (score 2):

Not currently. But we are working on enabling this scenario to allow users to pick their choice of VMs. Unfortunately, I don't have a date yet but will update thread as we are closer to it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a white paper or roadmap somewhere? All these ML platforms seem to be in alpha/beta and people (like me) are actively shopping around and could benefit from a sense of where things are headed, since the way they are now is not (I hope) the way any of them will be in several months.

Comment: neerajkh, any updates on this? Azure ML Studio super slow even with simple Linear Regressions.

Comment: can you please share your experiment in unlisted mode into gallery

Comment: is there anything happening? - @neerajkh